How to call a function from another workbook opened in another excel application
I have two workbooks. A sheet "A" create a new instance of Excel.Application, then it asks its workbook "A" to open a workbook "B" and get the result from a function in workbook "B".
I can manage to call workbook "B"'s function from sheet "A", but each time I call them from workbook "A" I have an error: Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)
Code that reproduce the error:
Workbook "A"
ThisWorkbook
Sub call_fun(ByRef wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox (wb.fun()) ' How to get the result?
End Sub

Sheet "A"
Sub sheet_main()
    Dim app As Excel.Application
    
    Set app = New Excel.Application
    ' Open the workbook B
    app.Workbooks.Open ("path\to\file\workbook B.xlsm")
    ' Call the workbook's a function
    ThisWorkbook.call_fun (app.ActiveWorbook)
    
    app.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    app.Quit
    Set app = Nothing
End Sub

Workbook "B"
ThisWorkbook
Function fun() As String
    fun = "Function from workbook B"
End Function


An alternative approach would be to call a sheet-scoped proxy method.
Move your fun() method to a Public Function in a new module in Workbook B.
Then, still in workbook B, add the following to Sheet1's code:
Public Function funProxy() As String
    funProxy = fun()
End Function

You can then call:
MsgBox wb.Sheets(1).funProxy

You can do this directly from Sheet1's code in Workbook A (you don't need the workbook-scoped function, although you can also do this if you need it).
However, I would recommend using BigBen's answer in preference, if it works for you. There is really no disadvantage (as far as I know) of passing the function name as a string, because the VBA compiler can't do anything with .fun anyway (so e.g. there would be no compile-time error with either approach if you got the function name wrong).

I adapted your solution to fit my problem. I put my code in a Module then I call it with Application.Run.

Using CallByName:
Sub call_fun(ByRef wb As Workbook)
    MsgBox CallByName(wb, "fun", VbMethod)
End Sub

Also note no parentheses around the parameter here (or in the MsgBox call above):
ThisWorkbook.call_fun app.ActiveWorbook


Unfortunalety, I couldn't get CallByName working on Workbook object. And can't call function written in Module.
